# JavaScript KeyDown event

Tags: javascript

I have the following function for example

```
function RequestInputType(Input) {
      inputType: Input
}
```

So now i want to call this function to cycle throug with an input value if key is pressed.

```
      window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        if (9 === e.keyCode) {
          e.preventDefault();
             RequestInputType(0)
//i Want it if key is pressed again then switch from RequestInputType(0) to RequestInputType(1)
             RequestInputType(1)
//and if pressed again
              RequestInputType(2)
//and so on
    }, false);
```

How do i go about that?

Comment: That function doesn't do anything. `inputType:` is a statement label that's ignored. The statement `Input` just evaluates the argument but doesn't do anything with it. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a keydown counter.

```
var keydownCounter = 0;

window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {

  if (9 === e.keyCode) {
     
     e.preventDefault();
     keydownCounter++
 
    
     if(keydownCounter % 3 == 0){
        RequestInputType(0)
     }
     else if(keydownCounter % 3 == 1){
        RequestInputType(1)
     }
     else if(keydownCounter % 3 == 2){
        RequestInputType(2)
     }
   }
},false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable to hold the current argument to pass to `requestInputType()`. Then you can increment it and wrap around after each call.

```
let curInputType = 0;
let maxInputType = 3;

window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (9 === e.keyCode) {
    e.preventDefault();
    RequestInputType(curInputType);
    curInputType = (curInputType + 1) % maxInputType;
  }
}, false);
```